# Which user sent an email campaign in EXM?

Tags: exm

How can I see which user created a campaign in Sitecore EXM, and which user scheduled or sent the campaign?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using Sitecore 9 with ExM built in, all of the ExM emails are stored in the following location:

`/sitecore/content/Email/Messages`

If you look inside the date named folders you will find the email campaigns you created in there. Each of these has the standard Sitecore fields for *Created By* & *Updated by*, in the *Statistics* section. This will give you the name of the user who created the campaign.